# Installing dependent background apk

Tags: android

I have a regular Android application which will be downloaded from a different source than Google Play Store. Assuming that the user will enable the "Install from unknown sources" option, this app can be installed. However, this application is dependent on another module (which has mostly services, no UI). I will prompt the user about this dependency during installation of the regular app.

Is there a way to auto-download this dependent module as an apk or a background task that runs in a different process space than the regular app?

When I go to Apps option in Settings, see a lot of processes running of the format com.<>.<> and others(like CoolEUKor) which were not installed by me. System apps can be preloaded. But, what about others. How are these processes installed without user interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to auto-download this dependent module as an apk or a background task that runs in a different process space than the regular app?

Use `DownloadManager`. Or, have a service that handles the downloading, where you use the `android:process` attribute to have that service run in a separate process.

Your third paragraph, though, implies that you are interest not merely in downloading the app but also installing it. While you can kick off an `ACTION_INSTALL_PACKAGE` activity, the user is still involved in the installation.

> When I go to Apps option in Settings, see a lot of processes running of the format com.<>.<> and others(like CoolEUKor) which were not installed by me.

Modern versions of stock Android do not have an option to view a process list in Settings. So, you might need to ask your device manufacturer about the specifics of what they are showing there.

A quick Internet search suggests that `CoolEUKor` is a bit of bloatware pre-installed on some Samsung devices. You would have to ask Samsung why Samsung pre-installs this app.

> How are these processes installed without user interaction?

They were pre-loaded, most likely, or are associated with apps that you installed but are not recognizing based on whatever information is showing up in that process list. Or, perhaps your device is infected with malware, and it is exploiting some security flaw on that device to install other apps.

Comment: Right, my motive was just not to download but for installing as well. Regarding the android:process setting for the background service, will this be a parent and child process where it gets destroyed once the main process is killed?

Comment: @HariniS: No, the processes should be independent. You're not forking the process; you are asking the system to fork a separate process for that component.

Comment: `A quick Internet search suggests that CoolEUKor is a bit of bloatware pre-installed on some Samsung devices.` Bloatwares are found literally on every third device these days. Found few malwares mining bitcoin on smartphone (they will not going to be millionaire but can buy their fav pizza every day) and adwares are like my PG.